# Can reversing into another vehicle damage your engine or other vital components?

Tags: engine, damage, accident

If you are reversing your car at a rate of about 5km/hr and you hit something in one of the following scenarios

A) a stationary vehicle

Or

B) a vehicle moving into your rear at a speed of at least 10km/hr

Will the sudden stopping caused by the external force in either or both of these scenarios cause any damage to your engine or any internal parts that are not considered body or cosmetic or electronics like sensors or cameras that don't impede drivability if they were broken.

Assume the car reversing is a normal sized car like sedan with engine in front and trunk at rear. The other vehicle size and weight is greater than or equal to the car in reverse.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Generally I'd suggest you wouldn't see any engine, transmission, or drivetrain damage. Anything is possible, though.

Comment: Is this part of an assignment?

Comment: @NumairAidroos no, this actually happened to me (scenario B) and I'm experiencing an issue with my engine a month later (specifically misfires at slow speed or idle that the mechanic has been unable to find cause or repair permanently).  Just curious if the two events are related in any way.

Comment: What kind of car is it? If NVH is bad enough the pcm  can pick it up as a false misfire. Or in your case likely coincidental.

Comment: @ben audi 2010 2.0 tfsi